# How to connect to node?

Tags: json-rpc, nodes, connections

I installed Ethereum on a VPS.

When I connect on the VSP, with the command line I can send transaction.

Now I want to do the same thing from a local script.

I think I must use [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC), but I don't understand how can I use it.
Moreover, there is some danger to use [RPC](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/29/security-alert-insecurely-configured-geth-can-make-funds-remotely-accessible/)

So is there an other way to do this?

Comment: What ethereum implementation do you use? Geth ?

Comment: @Gerbrand, yes I use Geth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Ethereum help:

```
API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS:
```

--rpc         Enable the HTTP-RPC server

--rpcaddr value   HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")

--rpcport value   HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545)

if you add --rpc the Geth Ethereum client will activate the rpc client. By default it'll use localhost so it's only accessible locally. If you use --rpcaddr , where YOURSERVERIPADDRESS is the public ip address of your server it'll be open for public.

Best to add a firewall rule. In Ubuntu/Linux you can use ufw for that.
However, if possible, I'd run the Ethereum client locally. Ethereum by its nature is able to run distributed :-).

Comment: I don't understand, for now I'm on testnet network. So I run this command on my VPS : `geth --rpc console` (the HTTP-RPC server is running). Now I open a new terminal ,but which command must I do to get access to my VPS locally?

Comment: If I run this command on my VPS `geth --rpc --testnet console` and this command on mac terminal `geth --rpdaddr "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" `console, I don't have access to my VPS accounts ... What is the problem?